# how to uninstall an rpm during the installation of new one

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

for an rpm based system, I need to change a package with another package while installing the new one. fg, installation of package2.rpm shall uninstall package1.rpm and continue its installation slightly. 
for this, I'm planning to erase package1 while installing package2 and call rpm -e at %pre section of package2.rpm. 
But I can not be sure if rpm locks the rpm database just after it works or just before  installation progress start. Sadly, since this is a concept problem for now, I do not have any linux system to try it out quickly.
Is it possible to use rpm -e at %pre section? or are there any way to do this with a single rpm package, because I would have to distribute the package as an rpm package.

Comment: Voting to close as this does not belong here....superuser.com would be a better fit....

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to handle this would be to include

```
Obsoletes: package1
```

in your package2 spec. When it is installed through yum package1 will be uninstalled automatically.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I've no chance to use yum. Just basic RPM is allowed :(

Comment: If you're using cmake you can set CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_OBSOLETES to enable this